# jQuery: How to get value inside elements using index or jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is much like slider presentation:**

```
<ul id='slider'>
   <li class="slide1">...</li>
   <li class="slide2">...</li>
   <li class="slide3">...</li>
   <li class="slide4 currentSlider">
      <div class="itemImage">../*image to display*/..</div>
      <span class="itemName">Bag</span>
      <span class="price">500</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I dynamically append `currentSlider` class in each `li` element whichever is on higher `z-index`(to diplay on top)

List of variables I already have:

1. sliderIndex = `li` container index number
2. sliderData = current slide jQuery object (li element)

**My Goal is to get the `price` value (*500*) inside `li currentSlider` class so I can format it to currency.**

My currency formatting code:

```
jQuery(function ($){
  mySlider.bind("slider.slide.onchange",function ( sliderIndex, sliderData ) {

 var price = $("span.price").html();

    $(".sliderPrice").text('$' + parseFloat(price , 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());

  });
});
```

I already have a final bunch of codes to make this things happened but **unfortunately sometimes** it shows/display the right currency format and **sometimes shows $NaN**. I mean NOT consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the price value from price element without using the current slider `li`, please use the current slide object to get the price value: `$("span.price",sliderData).html();`

```
jQuery(function ($){
  mySlider.bind("slider.slide.onchange",function ( sliderIndex, sliderData ) {
    var price = $("span.price",sliderData).html();
    $(".sliderPrice").text('$' + parseFloat(price , 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: It works @lokeshpahal but only on the first slide.. the rest of the price in each slides shows $NaN.
.currentSlider is a class dynamically appended whichever on top for display..

Comment: please try with the `currentSlider` class : `var price = $("span.price",'.currentSlider').html();`

Comment: Show $NaN again for each prices @lokeshpahal. But I like the way you use the object sliderData. The next slides will get undefined value. I tried using delay() but didn't work out.

Comment: Would you please provide jsfiddle for this so that we can take a look into code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var price =  $(".currentSlider .price").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
$(".sliderPrice").text('$' + parseFloat(price , 10).toFixed(2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6F7G/1/

You'd probably be better off filtering the numbers when you fill the  elements with prices, but this works nonetheless...

Comment: The result is still undefined. .currentSlider is my class dynamically appended to current li element.